# How to install QGIS 1.8 plugin Georeferencer?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

My question is about QGIS 1.8 georeferencer plugin.

I installed the new version of QGIS (1.8) but I don't have the georeferencer plugin, how do I install it?

I used the georeferencing plugin with QGIS 1.6 and now that I've upgraded to 1.8 I'd like to use it again, but it's not available! Am I doing something wrong?

I've gone to Plugins > Manage Plugins. I've searched for Georeferencer, but there were no results.

Answer (score 5):

please follow below steps:

1. Click "Plugins" --> "Manage Plugins"
2. Search "Georeferencer GDAL" in the Filter and Enable the plugin by tick the box
3. Click "OK"
4. Click "Raster" and you are able to use the Georeferencer Tool.

It seems that QGIS need to load each external plugin so you can find it in the menu bar.

http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html#load-core-plugin

Answer (score 0):

It should be available where you looked in Plugins>Manage Plugins. If it isn't you could try Plugins>Fetch Python Plugins.

Comment: with Fetch Python Plugins I don't find it, What is repository? There is a repository for GDAL georeferencer?

Comment: opening tells me though that has problems with ftools because there is an outdated plugin installed with an older version, but I don't think this is the problem ...

Comment: @jacpo: A repository is the location where all the official plugins are stored and that is where you should be able to download the plugin you are looking for. The Official repository is at http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml  and you should see it listed when you go to Plugins>Fetch Python Plugins and then look at the Repositories tab. If it is not listed the click on ADD and paste the URL above into URL field. Give the Repository a name, "Official Repository" will do. Then click OK.  That will give you a connection to the Official Repository. Fetch the plugin you want from there.

Comment: Hi nigel thanks for the suggestion but the problem is that the repository that I found with fetch python plugins there is,
the georeferencer plugin I've found in any repository
There is not even in "plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml"
I did not find nowhere the plugin, you know where I can find?

Comment: @jacopo: I am sorry but that is the only georeferencing plugin I can find and if you can not see it in the plugins already installed with your version of QGIS and you can not see it with Fetch Python plugins I can only think of a two problems. 1) Your later installed version of QGIS has problems with the remains of a previous installation 2) The plugin you are looking for is an earlier named plugin that is no longer available. Maybe somebody else here with more knowledge than me can help you.

Comment: Thanks nigel, I try to completely uninstall and reinstall it, to me seems like the only viable solution, thank you very much for the help you gave me

Comment: Georeferencer isn't a python plugin. It's a C++ plugin which comes with every default install.